# Does `go build`’s output flag `-o` have side-effects?

Tags: go, go-build

From [`go build`’s doc page](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies):

> The -o flag forces build to write the resulting executable or object to the named output file or directory, instead of the default behavior described in the last two paragraphs. If the named output is an existing directory or ends with a slash or backslash, then any resulting executables will be written to that directory.

However I’ve run into a building process that is essentially:

```bash
go build -o foo src/
mv foo bar
```

Is there any reason for doing this that I couldn’t find in documentation? E.g. does it set a linker symbol name to `foo` or something like that? Or is it just a quirk I can safely ignore?

Comment: The script might just be defending against partial output being read. Writing the whole thing to a new file first, then moving it to the final location could prevent weird issues. But that's just a guess on my part.

Comment: You may also get different results if folder `foo` and/or `bar` exists prior, play with what happens in each scenario.

Comment: @icza They’re both file names and not folders in this case, neither existing beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at checksums of `go build`-generated binaries with the same sources and different `-o` flags, the files are absolutely identical. So there is no side effect.